# Raster data on PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver

I need to publish raster and vector data through GeoServer WMS service and I have already chosen PostGIS as datasource to keep vector data.

Now I would like to know what is the best practice to work with raster data. 
I see two options:

- store raster data in PostGis and then use [ImageMosaicJDBC](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html) or [Postgis Raster Plug In](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html) (I read about some limitations and instability)
- store raster data somewhere on file system and setup GeoServer to read data from there.

I have little experience with GIS and I wonder if someone could suggest the best choice?

Comment: Which Version of PostGIS are you using - raster2pgsql for postgis 2.0 will load RASTERS into Postgis - GDAL is supported so you can have any raster format on this list load - http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html  see http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/RT_FAQ.html#id2988243

Comment: The problem is that you can setup Postgis just as vector data source and not as raster. You can do that only via plugins.

Comment: You can bypass WMS and serve it directly - http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/174-Minimalist-Web-based-ASP.NET-PostGIS-2.0-Spatial-GeometryRaster-Viewer.html

Comment: Raster data must be served by GeoServer WMS. It is a requirement I have to fulfill. Why don't store raster data on filesystem and keep just vector data on PostGis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the second option will be better. There is a lot of production deployment experience with GeoServer using filesystem based maps / tiles. As you've already deduced, PostGIS raster doesn't yet have that level of production use.

That isn't to say that PostGIS raster might not be a great case for some other uses - especially if you had a scenario where you're using it for WMS and other operation (e.g. via a thick client, or for some custom web application). It just doesn't seem worth the complexity for the scenario you are describing.